# Iterate over parameters for request

Tags: java, get, okhttp

I have a

```
Map<String,String> params = .....
```

with the key+value for the parameters for a GET request.

Building a HttpUrl looks something like this:

```
HttpUrl httpUrl = new HttpUrl.Builder()
                .scheme("https")
                .host("example.com")
                .addEncodedPathSegment("path")
                .addQueryParameter("name","John Doe")
                .build();
```

how do I add the (unknown beforehand and/or variable) parameters in `params` to the HttpUrl, i.e. iterate over the values in `params` and call `addQueryParameter` for each key+value?

EDIT sorry I was not specific enough: I need to know if I can call `.addQueryParameter()` repeatedly inside a loop somehow, *not* how to iterate over a Map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For it to work one must start with a HttpUrl.builder:

```
HttpUrl.Builder httpUrlBuilder = new HttpUrl.Builder()
                .scheme("https")
                .host("example.com");
```

followed by adding the parameters:

```
for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry: params.entrySet()) {
            httpUrlBuilder.addQueryParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

and finally building the request:

```
HttpUrl httpUrl = httpUrlBuilder.build();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(httpUrl)
                .get()
                .build();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to iterate your params Map, you can do this way:

```
Map<String, String> params = .....
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet())
{
   httpUrl.addQueryParameter(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue());

}
```

Comment: This will only work if you start with `HttpUrl.Builder httpUrl = new HttpUrl.Builder()
                .scheme("https")
                .host("example.com");`

Answer (score 2):

See the [HttpUrl Javadoc](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/HttpUrl.html) for examples.

```
HttpUrl url = HttpUrl.parse("https://twitter.com/search?q=cute%20%23puppies&f=images");
for (int i = 0, size = url.querySize(); i < size; i++) {
  System.out.println(url.queryParameterName(i) + ": " + url.queryParameterValue(i));
}
```

Comment: Very useful, but I have to go the other way _from_ params _to_ full URL

Comment: `OkHttpUrl.Builder` will let you do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("p1","a");
params.put("p2","b");
params.put("p3","c");
```

You can use:

```
paramString = urlEncodeUTF8(params)
```

It will return "p1=a&p2=b&p3=c".
You append it to the base of your url.

```
url = "https//example.com?" + paramString
```

Comment: urlEncoreUTF8 is contained in java.net.URLEncoder.
Also if you are working in Eclipse, you can type Ctrl + Shift + o to automatically import missing librairies.